# count distinct issue in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm trying to compute a number of (unique) apparition of each element in a Hive table column regarding other columns.

I tried this query, but I've this error Expression not in GROUP BY key custom

```
SELECT custom, dist_pt, dt, art, COUNT(DISTINCT art) OVER (PARTITION BY custom, dist_pt) as nb_art FROM Tab ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove DISTINCT from your COUNT() and add "GROUP BY art" at the end of your query. You need to segment, or group by, art in order to count how many records have each unique value of art.

Comment: Why are you suggesting the OP remove the `distinct`? He/She wants to count unique occurences, as fasr as I can tell?

Comment: I understood the OP as wanting to count how many records have each distinct value of `art`, not how many different `art` values there are.

Comment: I think you are correct. Counting distinct on a column in the group by will just return  1 every time.

Comment: Thanks Ethan J. but, I need to count occurences of each art indeed. Any other idea ?